# Need to compare two text files and sort them, using Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists in a text file, the first list is a store and a number (Ex: Store 007). The second list has a list of servers for all stores that have a format of 'x0007a', 'x0007b' and a separate name of servers in the same list with the format 'y0007a', 'y0007b'. What I need the program to do is to open the list of stores from file 1 and find the servers on file 2 and put it next to the store number.

It should look like:

```
1. Store 007    x0007a    y0007a
                x0007b    y0007b
```

I've tried in Excel but I'm barely getting into programming, I know how to call the files from python but I don't know where to go to next. Any help with a simple explanation for beginners would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the servers are identified by the number in the given format: x0<number>a? And please add the code you already have, so that we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Open the files and read their content

```
with open("file1.txt") as file1:
    con1 = file1.read()

with open("file2.txt") as file2:
    con2 = file2.read()
```

split the content (a string) into substrings

```
list1 = con1.split("\n") # stores
list2 = con2.split("\n") # servers
```

Dictionary to store the values

```
dictionary = {}
```

Move the substrings together
by first going through all key-value pairs and then assigning them into your dictionary.

`for i in range(len(list1)):
     dictionary[list1[i]] = list2[i]`

Comment: I assume your values in the files are each in a new line